# database is showing all 0's when the checked boxes should show one

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am rather new to programming in general. I am creating an webpage where the user selects a process from a sql populated dropdown list. A grid view then populates with the corresponding results with checkboxes. The end user can select a checkbox and that should save the value 1 to the database so that I can retrieve the checked items for another grid view later. Unfortunately it is only populating zeros. How can i fix this?

```
 protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox checkBox1 = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox);

            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                string updateData = "update AuditChecklist$ set IsSelected = @IsSelected";
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateData, con);
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsSelected", 1);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

            }
           else if(!checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                string updateData = "update AuditChecklist$ set IsSelected = @IsSelected";
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateData, con);
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsSelected", 0);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }

        }
```

Tried the following code as suggested but I am still having the same issue. I have included my design and ASP code for further help.

```
 protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox checkBox1 = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox);



            string updateData = "update AuditChecklist$ set IsSelected = @IsSelected";

                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateData, con);
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsSelected", checkBox1.Checked ? 1 : 0);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

        }

 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="377px" Width="764px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FAST_Screen" HeaderText="FAST Screen" SortExpression="FAST_Screen">
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Audit_Detail" HeaderText="Audit Detail" SortExpression="Audit_Detail">
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
    </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:QMSAuditConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [FAST Screen] AS FAST_Screen, [Audit Detail] AS Audit_Detail, [EPS Process] AS EPS_Process, [IsSelected] FROM [AuditChecklist$] WHERE ([EPS Process] = @EPS_Process)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="LstProcess" Name="EPS_Process" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

[Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpccV.png)

Comment: related - don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: Tried that and now I get all 0's

Comment: cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IsSelected", checkBox1.Checked ? 1 : 0));
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();

Comment: Your update statement has a MAJOR problem. There is no where clause. This means it is going to update the ENTIRE table over and over (for each row in your grid).

Comment: Thank you @SeanLange! I appreciate the explanation and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you set the [ThreeState](http://System_Windows_Forms_CheckBox_Checked) property of CheckBox to ***true***, so it must be changed to ***false***.

It doesn't need write same codes twice only for one check condition.

```
CheckBox checkBox1 = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox);

string updateData = "update AuditChecklist$ set IsSelected = :@IsSelected";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateData, con); 
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsSelected", checkBox1.Checked ? 1 : 0);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Also it will be better if an  update statement has any filter (using where clause).

Comment: If I only need to place this once, do I need to still insert this in an if statement? Also getting System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ':'.' exception.

Comment: So sorry. I have a mistake, however I have edit the answer.

Comment: I am confused. How do I set the Three state property to False?

Comment: A. You can change directly from designer: 1) open the form from designer. 2) select the checkbox control. 3) set ThreeState value from Properties window. B. Also you can change from the onload event: checkbox1.ThreeState = false;